# GitHub Action parse label to select targets for matrix job

Tags: json, terraform, yaml, github-actions, jq

I am very much new to GitHub action. Trying to construct a workflow that can give me list of target directory based on latest label, that I can put in matrix job for further processing (terraform apply).

my `labeler.yml` has below paths that I am using with `actions/labeler@v4` to add respective labels in my main pull_request workflow without any issues.

```
dev_us-west-1: env/dev/us-west-1/*
tst_us-west-2: env/tst/us-west-2/*
prd_eu-west-1: env/prd/eu-west-1/*
```

The second workflow: Here I want to fetch labels and based on that I want to select the respective target directories. Below is my unfinished workflow that can now fetch the labels in JSON array. however how to fetch the label name from the output and loop through the `labeler.yml` file to get a list of directories that I can use for further processing?

```
name: label_target_check
on:
  issue_comment:
  
permissions:
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write
  issues: write
  
jobs:
  help:
    if: ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request && startsWith(github.event.comment.body, 'apply') }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fetch PR Branch
        uses: xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch@v2
        id: comment-branch

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ steps.comment-branch.outputs.head_ref }}

      - name: Generate token
        uses: tibdex/github-app-token@v1
        id: get_installation_token
        with: 
          app_id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
          private_key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - uses: octokit/request-action@v2.x
        id: get_latest_label
        with:
          route: GET /repos/${{ github.repository }}/issues/${{ github.event.issue.number }}/labels
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ steps.get_installation_token.outputs.token }}

      - run: "echo labels: '${{ steps.get_latest_label.outputs.data }}'"
```

The label output from the issue:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5447687240,
    "node_id": "LA_kwDOJME-rhrtrtjnK1lSA",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrg/MyRepo/labels/dev_us-west-1",
    "name": "dev_us-west-1",
    "color": "ededed",
    "default": false,
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5898781642,
    "node_id": "LA_kwDOJME-derhehehK1lSg",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrg/MyRepo/labels/prd_eu-west-1",
    "name": "prd_eu-west-1",
    "color": "ededed",
    "default": false,
    "description": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with `jq` and `yq`:

```bash
labels=$(jq -r '.[].name' <<< '${{ steps.get_latest_label.outputs.data }}')
for label in $labels; do
  yq ".$label" < labeler.yml
done
```

With your above JSON, the output will be:

```
env/dev/us-west-1/*
env/prd/eu-west-1/*
```

You may further handle this according to your use case.